# MS Access VBA to set background color of individual fields in individual records

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-cursor

I have programs to do this in Excel and I'm trying to find out if it's possible in Access.

**Scenario:**  Pipe-delimited patient records of auto accidents are downloaded from hospitals, containing account numbers, lastname, etc., street address, hospital name.

Some accounts are "related", e.g., two people in the same accident.  So surnames **probably** will be the same, street addresses will (almost) match, and account numbers will be close.

Addresses "almost" match means, e.g.:

Smith|John|123 Jones St|1234567

Smith|Mary|123 Jones Street|1234569

The full list might be 90 accounts, with maybe 3 sets of "relateds" (7 accounts total).

In Excel I sort by Street Address. Then it colors the cell background purple if everything before the space and the next two characters match. So it would color-flag these as "related".  Then I sort by "Guarantor surname" (i.e., the person responsible to pay, not shown in the example), and color match surnames with a green background.  Then I sort by "Patient surname" and color match those with a blue background.

It can't be done with filters--I need to see all the records each time because manual inspection is also necessary.

**SO IN ACCESS,** the records would be imported into a cursor, and then the cursor would be sorted by address--manually examined--then sorted by Guarantor Surname--and manually examined--then sorted by Patient Surname--and manually examined a third time.

I have already set up Access import code, but no "relateds" checks are done for those imports.

I'm looking for how I could color-flag individual fields in individual records--while they are being displayed in a cursor.

An alternative could be that after they are imported just dump the set into an Excel and modify the existing Excel code, but if it's not difficult I would prefer to do it all in Access.

Most of the Excel code is in subroutines that cycle through "Start at this row, and go until Cell R is empty".  So if it's fairly easy to change an Access field+row entry background in a cursor, reworking the Excel code wouldn't be a big deal.

I'm pretty new to Access.

Comment: On form must use Conditional Formatting. Can use VBA in report OnFormat or OnPrint events but better to use Conditional Formatting.

Comment: I don't understand the comment. I'm not looking to print anything or create a report. The records are pulled into Excel from CSV, then routines change some cell colors based on criteria. The Excel is not saved. I'm looking for a way to change individual field displays in an Access CURSOR pulled with Select. I don't want to color a field COLUMN, I want to change individual fields in the cursor.

Comment: Although I would still like to know if there is a way to color them only in Access, after I posted the question I got to thinking that it probably would be better to dump from Access to Excel. The existing Excel code can also do things like Google a name + city/address for the current row, create a list of accounts over $45k, spot garbage addresses ("UNKNOWN"), etc., select/unselect rows to be added as "related", spot problem names ("SMITHGOMEZ", space or hyphen omitted: Smith-Gomez), etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the cursor"? - that makes no sense to me. I already described the only ways to accomplish what your question title asks.

Comment: In SQL the output of a query is in the "CURrent Set Of Records", abbreviated CURSOR.  That isn't stored anywhere--it's basically like importing a CSV file into Excel before you save the import.

I don't understand your comment.  What I'm looking for is that once a query has pulled records into the memory cursor (which displays as rows and fields), is there a way to color individual DISPLAYED record field backgrounds--equivalent to color Excel A12, B6, G19 green?

Comment: How would a recordset in memory display color - where would this display? Recordset must be associated with a form or report for anything to display and get color. Use Conditional Formatting.